# Ajax call from custom html in webview not caputed with shouldInterceptRequest

Tags: android, ajax, webview

I have this simple app where I load a WebView with an HTML that contains an ajax call on a button.
I expect my function 'shouldInterceptRequest' to capture that request and send something back (for now is a String but it will be an )

Here is my code for the WebViewActivity:

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

```
private WebView webView;
private Uri picUri;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


    String newHTML = "<!doctype html><html><head>"+
    "<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>"+
    "<script>"+
        "function myCall() {"+
            "var request = $.ajax({"+
                "url: \"ajax.php\","+
                "type: \"GET\","+            
                "dataType: \"html\""+
            "});"+
            "request.done(function(msg) {"+
                "$(\"#mybox\").html(msg);"+          
            "});"+

            "request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {"+
                "alert( \"Request failed: \" + textStatus );"+
            "});"+
        "}"+
    "</script>"+
            "<meta charset=\"utf-8\" />"+
            "<title>My jQuery Ajax test</title>"+
            "<style type=\"text/css\">"+
                "#mybox {"+
                    "width: 300px;"+
                    "height: 250px;"+
                    "border: 1px solid #999;"+
                "}"+
            "</style>"+
        "</head>"+
        "<body>"+
            "The following div will be updated after the call:<br />"+
            "<div id=\"mybox\">"+
            "</div>"+
            "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Update\" />"+
        "</body>"+
    "</html>";



    webView.loadData(newHTML, "text/html", "UTF-8");


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {


                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url+" captured");

        }

    });
}
}
```

For some reason I'm not capturing that ajax call.
What am I doing wrong?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest was my problem!, I didnt have a section with NETWORK! So what I did was in the manifest, at the end, add:

NETOWRK:
*

So the way this works is, whatever I had before the `NETWORK` was being cached and if something wasn't there there was no way to know what to do. With this statement whatever we havent in cache, we get it from the NETWORK

Comment: How to add NETOWRK: * in manifest please give some example for that.